# E-ticket, booking reference number validation throw Amadeus api call

Tags: amadeus

Is it possible to validate booking reference number or e-ticket + passenger name over Amadeus API?

Answer (score 0):

In the Enterprise APIs, there are APIs helping the customers to validate the reservations they are allowed to access. If you refer to an API that validates tickets belonging to any traveler, that’s not possible as it is not GDPR compliant. You can only validate the reservation/e-ticket/passenger of the reservation you have created.